# How to include space in a hyperlink target using reStructuredText?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, targeting

I can do this:

```
For more info, see Target_.

.. _Target: http://google.com
```

This correctly generates documentation that links `Target` to "http://google.com".

I want to replace Target with text that has spaces:

```
For more info, see Text With Space_.

.. _Text With Space: http://google.com
```

The above example generates documentation that incorrectly links "Space" to an unknown location.  I want it to link "Text With Space" to "http://google.com".

How can I achieve this?

Comment: In the Sphinx ReST context these are called [target](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#hyperlink-targets) and [hyperlink](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#hyperlinks), the term [anchor](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.1.3) is best applied strictly in the HTML context.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the Sphinx documentation for [Hyperlinks, External links](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/rest.html#hyperlinks).

> Use `Link text <http://example.com/>`_ for inline web links.
>
> ```
> `Link text <http://example.com/>`_
> ```
>
> You can also separate the link and the target definition (ref), like this:
>
> ```
> This is a paragraph that contains `a link`_.
>
> .. _a link: http://example.com/
> ```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
.. |Target| replace:: Text With Space
.. _Target: http://google.com

For more info, see |Target|_
```

Comment: This is horrible. I love it.